# Page keeps redirecting on validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What I'm trying to do is a basic validation after a form is submitted, I am using vuejs alongside with laravel but in the blade itself there is a form that 
gets submitted.

Upon submission we go into the controller the validate the stuff user sent, NOW here is the problem when one of the inputs are empty, then the page goes in a redirect loop, resulting of `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

the blade file that we need to be returned is "joborder/create" and we get to send to store function to check the validation.
I had to use create as a post so I overwrite the default from the resource.

I have no idea what's causing the loop.
I'm using laravel 5.2

Any help would highly appreciable.

Route :

```
Route::resource('joborder' ,'JoborderController');
Route::POST('joborder/create','JoborderController@create');
```

Blade File :

```
<div class="pubdiv col-md-12" >


        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'JoborderController@store','method' =>'POST']) !!}
              {{ csrf_field() }}
     <h3>basicinput</h3>
     <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 pull-right">
               <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('company' , 'ComapnyName')!!} 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="owner" value="{{$company_owner->name}}"  disabled>
           </div>
       <div class="form-group ">
                <input type='submit'  value="finish" name="submit" style="margin-top:4px" class="col-md-12 btn btn-t-primary btn-theme">

              </div>

          {!! Form::close() !!} <!-- end form post a job -->
```

Controller :

```
  if(session()->get('role_active') != 1){
      return redirect('thehood')->with('error','NO CAN DO');
  }else{
   $this->validate($request, [
           'alljobs_id' => 'required',
           'joborder_id' => 'required',
           'notes'=>'required',
           'state' =>'required',
           'city' => 'required',
           'type' => 'required',
           'salary' => 'required',
           'created_at' => 'required'
        ]);

   // after moving these remove the keys from request
   $alljobs_id = $request->alljobs_id;
   $joborder_id = $request->joborder_id;
   $request->request->remove('joborder_id');
   $request->request->remove('alljobs_id');

   $check_prof + $check_prof_custom  = 9;
   if(($check_prof + $check_prof_custom < 5 ) || ($check_behv + $check_behv_custom < 5 )){
     return redirect('joborder/create')->with('error','5 input is required!');
   }

  }
```

**UPDATE**: I've noticed I have both post and get method which was wrong so I made a new function called creates with (s)

```
|        | POST      | joborder/crawltitle         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\JoborderController@crawltitle              | web           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | joborder/create             | joborder.create  | App\Http\Controllers\JoborderController@create                  | web           |
|        | POST      | joborder/creates            |                  | App\Http\Controllers\JoborderController@creates                 | web           |
|        | POST      | joborder/moveAttrib
```

the new function now if the validation fails it redirects me to 404 page but my address bar is /joborder/creates/

Comment: I don't see any GET route to joborder/create, how can you redirect to it?

Comment: You have an extra closing curly brace

Comment: Could you run `php artisan route:list` and add the output to your post?

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a method GET on your resource

```
Route::resource('joborder' ,'JoborderController');
```

When you call the redirect function `redirect('joborder/create')` you are redirecting to the resource above with the argument `create`.

Try `redirect('joborder')` instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: its like one step closer , i need the user to be redirected to joborder/create , not joborder itself

Comment: do you have that route as GET type? the one you show us its a POST one, you cannot redirect to it

Comment: no i changed the route to a new one called "joborder/creates" now i see the errors but on a 404 page!and it happens on "$this->validate" when  there is a empty value!

Comment: why you don't create a store request? its a validator but it works before controller method. check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: so with this i dont need to do validation on controller right ? and how do i implement it for only one of my function ?

Comment: right! just replace function(Request $request) to function(App\Path\MyStoreRequest $request) and its done.